# Android spinner, setting error on specific item

Tags: android, android-spinner

How do I set an error when a specific item is selected on my spinner. Let's say my spinner has 0, 1, 2, 3 in it and I want it to error only when 0 is chosen and prompt the user to select something else. Is it possible, if so does it require a huge workaround?

Comment: I don't quite follow. I want to set an error when 0 is selected that's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an ItemSelectedListener to the spinner, and inside of it, you do the stuff:

```
 spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        if(position==<desired_position>){
            //Do some stuff
        }

 }
```